# 16sec to insert 1000 rows in a SQLite DB on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I tried to insert 1000 rows in my sqlite db, but it took more than 16 sec.. Is there something wrong in my code that I didn't see ?

```
 NSLog(@"--start--");

 if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
  static sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

  for(int k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
   sqlite3_exec(database, [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into myTable (id, name) values ('%i', 'a')", k] UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL);

  sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);

  sqlite3_close(database);
 }

 NSLog(@"--stop--");


start : 2010-11-27 11:21:11.704 
stop  : 2010-11-27 11:21:27.908
```

thx !

Answer (score 13):

This is due to SQLite's auto-committing. You need to call `sqlite3_exec`with:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
```

Now insert all your records as before. After you are done with that. Execute:

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

That should do the trick.

Also [this FAQ question](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q19) will explain why it is so much slower. It's actually much faster than a few dozen queries per second as stated in the FAQ, but due to the nature of flash memory on the iPhone, that would seem to normal.

Answer (score 7):

I finally added those 2 lines around my insert queries :

```
sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN", 0, 0, 0);

sqlite3_exec(database, "COMMIT", 0, 0, 0);


start : 2010-11-27 13:07:26.022
stop  : 2010-11-27 13:07:26.285
```

thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to do a bulk insert instead of doing 1000 trips to sql

Comment: hum.. tried to get code examples, but couldn't find one that works.. how would you do it ? thx

Comment: just create the whole string for the insert queries separated by a semicolun in the loop. after the loop terminates, send the query just once.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you do the inserts in one transaction?
SQLite is extreamly slow if you auto commit on each insert.

Comment: well, i thought, but i'll try to do a bulk insert to see if i got  better performances

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)doBatchExecution
{
    const char *dbpath = [[DatabaseManager getDataBasePath] UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &db) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
      char* errorMessage;
      sqlite3_exec(db, "BEGIN TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &errorMessage);


      NSString *query=@"YOUR_SQL_QUERY";

      if (sqlite3_exec(db, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMessage) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"DB Error. category transacation '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(db));


      sqlite3_exec(db, "COMMIT TRANSACTION", NULL, NULL, &errorMessage);
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No hard numbers here, but it's about what I'd expect. Use bulk insertion, maybe try different bundle sizes as well.